# Buggy cursor in FireMonkey (Delphi XE2)

Tags: delphi, cursor, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, memo

Delphi XE2 update 3, Windows 7.

I have a memo, it's cursor is `crIBeam`. But when I move a mouse over the memo the cursor changes to `crDefault` and back. The swap repeats vary fast. I took a picture with the `crDefault` cursor but `crIBeam` must be instead.

[image]

How to prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that XE2 Update 4 is due very soon.

Release notes are available here

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Release_Notes_for_XE2_Update_4

The notes refer to multiple updates, especially FMX controls, and TMemo is specifically mentioned.

It may be worth your while waiting for this release before you spend too much more time 'debugging' this.